# Let $a,b,c,d$ be $∈ ℝ$ and let A=$\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Background**

Find values of a,b,c,d such at $A^T$=-A and $det(A)≠0$

**My work so far**

$$\begin{pmatrix}-3 & -5 \\ -7 & -9\end{pmatrix}^T$$

which equals

$$\begin{pmatrix}-3 & -7 \\ -5 & -9\end{pmatrix}$$

and $det(A)=-8$, which satisfies $A^T$=-A and $det(A)≠0$

However, I need to find values for a,b,c,d all non-zero, such that $A^2=l_2$. How would I go about doing this? Would this simply be the inverse, such as

$$\begin{pmatrix}-3 & -5 \\ -7 & -9\end{pmatrix}$$

which equals

$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{9}{8} & \frac{-5}{8} \\ \frac{-7}{8} & \frac{3}{8}\end{pmatrix}$$

or am I incorrect here?

Comment: How is $A^ T=-A$ for your choice?

Comment: $A^T$ does not equal $-A$ in your example.

Comment: $A^T=-A$ means $a=d=0, b=-c$. Then $\det A\ne 0 \iff b\ne 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are my suggestions:

1. Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ c& d\end{bmatrix}$.
2. *Without choosing specific values for* $a,b,c,d$, write out what $A^T$ is. If you can't remember, look in your book.
3. The same way, write out what $-A$ is.
4. Does the transpose do anything to the diagonal?
5. Is there any number such that $x = -x$?
6. Write out what $\det A$ is.
7. What needs to be true about the off-diagonal elements for both $A^T = -A$ and $\det A \neq 0$?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I'll consider these when I work on this problem. However, I notice that I'm really lacking in knowledge in this area and need to study more on this.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have misunderstood what a transpose is:$$A^T=\begin{pmatrix}a & c \\ b & d\end{pmatrix}$$

So we want $a=d=0,\,c=-b,\,ad-bc=b^2\ne0$ i.e. $b=0$.